# How to filter out links from html using grep or sed?

Tags: command-line, grep, sed

I am trying to filter the links related to the `src` attribute from the html of a web page.

I used `curl` to get the html and below `sed` command to filter the url links.

```
curl -s http://www.example.com/ | sed -n '/src/,/jpg/p'
```

My idea was to filter out the lines which starts with `src` and ends with `.jpg` extension. But it didn't work and it prints out the entire html. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
curl -s http://www.example.com | grep -Po '(?<=src=")[^"]*(jpg|png)'
```

**Explanation**:

From `man grep`:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)
```

The lookbehind `(?<=src=)` asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is the characters `src=`. Then we're looking for everything except `"` that ends with jpg or png.

Comment: It works perfect. Could you please explain how this works? And what if I want to sort out `.png` also?

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus: I've added some explanations and support for png. You can add gif as follow `(jpg|png|gif)` if needed